# Is it possible to return a html table from a WebMethod?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

Using a WebMethod, I get a value needed to create a HTML Table and populate it. 
Once it's done, I need the Table to be displayed.

Is it possible ?

Comment: What are you calling the WebMethod from?  ASP.Net?  JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can a web service return an HTML table? Yes. *Should* you do it that way? Probably not. Please consider 'separating the concerns' so that the service is responsible only for returning the data. Then the consumer of the data can format it as needed. One possible implementation would be for the service to return XML and the 'presenter' to transform it with XSLT into the desired Table. In the long run, the code will be easier to maintain and understand. (Trust me; I've seen a project that had 2,500+ lines of string concatenation that built an HTML string. NOT fun!) As an added bonus, the web service's response will be much smaller.

Comment: I used the webmethods for the first time, and thanks to you, I realized I used it the wrong way :) Instead, I used the webmethod to only get a value on the server side. This way, I've been able to use this value as  a parameter in a method, which created the HTMLTable for me. Thanks for the good advice !

Comment: Glad to hear it! Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a string from a WebMethod, which means you could return a string that represents html... then render that string (taking care of required encoding) I cant say much more that that not knowing any more...

Answer (score 0):

Create the markup in a variable and do `Response.Write`.

```
StringBuilder strHtml=new StringBuilder();
strHtml.Append("<table>");
strHtml.Append("<tr><th>Name</th></tr>");
strHtml.Append("<tr><td>Jon</td></tr>");
strHtml.Append("<tr><td>Marc</td></tr>");
strHtml.Append("<tr><td>Jared</td></tr>");
strHtml.Append("</table>");
Response.Write(strHtml.ToString());
```